# The prepositions "for" & "to"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I hope this question is not a duplicate because I reviewed other posts.
I just want to make sure that I have the right meaning in these specific examples. 
If I was watching a movie portraying a technologically advanced device and I commented:

"**This is not impressive for me."**

This means I am comparing what I am watching to my knowledge, intellectual ability, etc, and I have come to the conclusion that is isn't that impressive. However, to someone of below my intellectual level, might say this is impressive for him.

However, if I commented:

**"This is impressive to me"**

This doesn't mean I am comparing or judging the work went behind that device, I am just saying this is impressive according to how it is being portrayed or it sounds/looks impressive.

Is that true?

Comment: Would you use the same prepositions if the forms were reversed?  Move the '***not***' from the first to the second sentence.

Comment: "This is not impressive to me" meaning it doesn't sound impressive. "This is impressive for me" meaning according to my knowledge, this is deemed impressive

Comment: Are you translating it literally to or from some other language more familiar to you?

Comment: I heard the line "It is impressive, for theoretical work." in Big Bang theory. And I thought that it meant it is only impressive for theoretical work or that by theoretical work standards, it is impressive. And I thought that if I said "it is impressive for me" will mean the same thing. That according to my thinking, knowledge, etc, it is impressive.

Comment: "It is impressive, for theoretical work" is a different structure. It is (adj.) for (sth). Here, It means " It works really good in terms of theoretical calculation". But you, I think, you can be passionate for sth , but you cannot say It is impressive for me ! It sounds odd to me, an English learner ! You can be happy for sth and you can be impressed by sth. I hope it helps you

Comment: for (sth) is modifying the adjective impressive (I think). **similar to** :  It is **ready for eating**. it is  **easy for learning**

Comment: Thank you for explaining. But " It works really good in terms of theoretical calculation" is the wrong meaning. The line meant to degrade theorical and the girl who said the line meant condescension and that it is only impressive by theorical work standards.

Comment: The girl in the big bang theory said, "It is impressive, for theoretical work" that was met with a question "Do I detect a hint of condescension?" So, "it is impressive, for theoretical work" meaning that according to theoretical work standards, it is impressive, however, to some other fields, it is not impressive.  Here is the link for it. https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-4-episode-03-the-zazzy-substitution/

Comment: @VictorBazarov I am eager to see your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27406/discussion-between-ghaith-alrestom-and-cardinal).

Comment: "*It is impressive, for theoretical work*" rewritten would be "*It is impressive, **as far as** theoretical works **go***".  "*It is impressive for me*" might be OK in the context of talking of your achievements. "*I just reached 1000 points in Mahjong on Windows.  It is impressive for me*", meaning "*it is impressive if you consider just my accomplishments*".

Comment: It really works best with no prepositional phrase.  "This is impressive." <-- period --the end.  Because "impressions" are always personal, saying " to me" or "for me" adds no meaning. You might say "It was impressive to **him** (although that is simpler stated as "It impressed him.")

Comment: @close-voters, please do not close any non-trivial questions about prepositions as answered by dictionaries. Dictionary entries on prepositions only scratch the surface of usage, and are very terse besides.

Answer (score 1):

> This is impressive **to** me.

is the usual way to say what I think you mean (more specific context would be helpful).
See [*to*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to_1):

> 6. preposition
>      You use **to** to indicate who or what an action or a feeling is directed towards.

Meaning as you see "this", or the concept of "this" comes to you, it is (not) impressive.

As for:

> This is not impressive **for** me.

The only related definition I could find was [*for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for_1):

> 5. preposition
>      If you feel a particular emotion for someone, you feel it on their behalf.

Meaning my feeling is that it is (not) impressive.  But in your example doesn't make a lot of literal sense. In the same sense, you could say something like:

> I went out with her a few times, but she was not a good match **for** me.

Answer (score 1):

**English likes verbs**. Impressive is an adjective, yes.

**An impressive building, an impressive resume.**

but: the verb, **impress** here is better to express the OP's idea.

[X: subject] does not impress me.

**The technology does not impress me.**

Generally speaking, **if some thing is not impressive, we have no reason to add either to me or for me.** We would express this as: **I don't think x is impressive.**

Answer (score 0):

> This is not impressive for me (or X).

This typically means the following:

- You did or saw something.
- Someone else said it was impressive.
- You know you (or X) could have done better, or have seen better, so you are saying they are wrong and it's really not impressive.

In the case of where "this" is something you've seen rather than done yourself, this can seem rude or snobbish.

> This is impressive to me.

You consider this impressive.  "To me" acknowledges that others might think differently.